# only progress wheel in progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show a progress dialog when my activity is busy preparing something.

The problem is i just want the progress wheel being shown NOT the dialog screen with it.

Currently am showing a progress dialog with the black dialog on which the progress wheel spinning.

Take the image as a reference.(bottom right corner).[image]

Comment: is what your looking for, just the wheel nothing else? If so there is such a thing as a circular progressbar.

Comment: yes am looking for that wheel ONLY. android has a circular progress bar but it also supplies a background like dialog which i don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will add a progress bar without the dialog at the bottom of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ProgressBar
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
     android:layout_width="32dip"
     android:layout_height="32dip">
  </ProgressBar>      
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your XML layout where you want the "progress wheel".

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:id="@+id/marker_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout in a relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <yourlayout....>
    </yourlayout>

    <ProgressBar....
         android:visibility = "gone"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then whenever you want the to show and hide the progress, just set the visibility to gone/visible.I'm fairly certain that you can have a transparent background for the progress bar, so it will give you just the wheel.